# Visual Studio 2022 folder being created automatically in Documents

Tags: visual-studio-2022

How do can I stop Visual Studio folder being created in Documents (C:\Users\Username\Documents) every time I start up Visual Studio 2022?

I have tried changing the settings in Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Locations and this does not work.